# Access 2013 web app - restoring previous app snapshot package without reverting data (structured staging environment)

Tags: azure, sharepoint, ms-access-2013, snapshot

I have a reasonably complex Access 2013 web app which is now in production on hosted O365 Sharepoint.  I would like to take a backup (package snapshot) into a test environment, and then migrate this to production once development is complete (I certainly don't want to do development on the production system!).  The problem is that the snapshot also backs up all data so uploading the new package over the top of the existing package in the sharepoint app repository reverts the data to the time of snapshot as well.  Alternatively, rolling back to the original snapshot if there are issues would lose all data after the new package was applied.

I can easily get a second version of the app going by saving as a new application etc but this creates a new product ID etc in the app store.  We also use a Access 2013 desktop accdb frontend to hook directly into the Azure SQL database to do all the stuff that the web app can't provide (formatted reports etc) so I cant just create a new app every time without dealing with all of the credential and database renaming issues.

So my question is, does anybody know how to safely operate a test environment for Access 2013 web app development?  One needs to be able to apply an updated version, or rollback to the old one if there are problems without rolling back the data.  With the desktop client I can just save a new copy of the accdb file every time obviously.  I dont mind creating a new instance or link to the app on sharepoint each time, however this obviously generates a totally new database (server name, db location, login id's etc) as well.  You would hope there is a way to upload and replace your app without touching the data, else how else can you develop without working directly in production?

Any answers would be really appreciated.

Thanks.